# HTML - CSS Navbar dropdown

Tags: php, html, css

**I'd like to create a dropdown menu from the profile section of the navbar. How can I do that?**
I've tried looking it up but I didn't found any good sulotion that fits my ides. (I'd like this dropdown menu to contain 2 items.)

```css
*{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #141424;
    color: #787884;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.avatar{
vertical-align: middle;
}
ul li {
    padding: 30px 40px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul li a{
    font-family: "Magic Mushroom";
}
a:hover{
    color: white;
}
ul li:hover a{
    background-color: #454552;
}
ul li:hover{
    background-color: #454552;
}
ul li a img{
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.nav{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #787884;
}
.active{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Main page</a></li>
        <li><a href="servers.php">Servers</a></li>
        <li><a href="rules.php">Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="vip.php">VIP</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not that much stylish but like regular ones you see on other websites
also don't forget to run it on your own browser
try to make it responsive
you are using "px" that is not a good idea for declaring measures
try to use "vh" for height and "vw" for width

```css
*{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #141424;
    color: #787884;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.avatar{
vertical-align: middle;
}
ul li {
    padding: 30px 40px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
ul li a{
    font-family: "Magic Mushroom";
}
a:hover{
    color: white;
}
ul li:hover a{
    background-color: #454552;
}
ul li:hover{
    background-color: #454552;
}
ul li a img{
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.nav{
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #787884;
}
.active{
    color: white;
}
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    width: 40vw;
    top: 120px;
    display: flex;
    z-index: -1;
    flex-direction: column;
    right: 10%;
    background-color: #454552;
}
.profile:hover .dropdown{
    height: 10vh;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="hu">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Farkas">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Main page</a></li>
        <li><a href="servers.php">Servers</a></li>
        <li><a href="rules.php">Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="vip.php">VIP</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="profile"><a href="profile.php">Profile</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```